# What to do about the office farter?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

There is an older man who comes in a couple days a  week and he farts really loud without excusing himself. How do I tell him he is being impolite in a nice way?

Comment: Is the fact that he's being impolite (not excusing himself) more important, or the fact that he's farting often? You might get better results by politely suggesting that he use Beano, or some other supplement.

Comment: You say older man, is there a possibility it is a medical issue and he has no control over it? He may not even realize he is doing it

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing what position you and the older man hold in the company

Comment: To add to @雰囲気読めない人 , if the man have/had cancer on their bowel/anal area, they can't control this. I have a friend that worked for CancerCare research and one of his teammates had it.

Comment: I second @employee-X's request for clarification.  What exactly are you hoping to achieve?  That he stops farting? Or that he start apologising?  The latter is achievable; the former is not.